# How to remember a variable in JQuery for next AJAX load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I load data set by Jquery AJAX as

```
$(function(){
 $('#next').submit(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var form = $(this);
 var page = form.attr("action")
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: page, 
   success: function(html){
   $("#results").append(html);
   }
  });
 });
});
```

The form is a single button with action="load.php?page=2".

When pressing submit button of the form, it will load data from `load.php?page=2`. How can I remember this action to load data from `load.php?page=3` upon next click? and reading subsequent pages?

In fact, I want to introduce a new variable for the page number will be increased upon every click.

Comment: what do you what to remember? the number 2 and 3? you get them by $_GET['page']. if you what to know how to make the next request with the following number, just make a `<input type='hidden' id='page'> and increase its value. otherwise, please explain what you want to remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just set a javascript var to represent page and then increment it on submit...

```
var page = 1;
$(function(){
 $('#next').submit(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();

 var form = $(this);
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: page, 
   success: function(html){
       $("#results").append(html);
       page += 1;
   }
  });
 });
});
```

I don't know what your original page var had in it, but obviously you would tailor this response to fit your needs. your url param would not just be a single number, obviously, so update that part as you need.

Comment: You may want to call the variable `page_number` instead of `page` and it would be passed as `data: {page: page_number}`, not in the `url`. You might want to put this whole block inside a closure so it doesn't leak the `page_number` variable. (Although if this is all the code you plan on having in the block above, then it's not a concern.)

Answer (score 3):

I would use an RegEx to slice the number from the end of the `action` attribute and replace the `action` in the `success` handler with the incremented page number.

I've also changed the line `b.attr("action")` to `form.attr("action")` as I think that is a typo in your version. If not stay with the original version of that line :)

```
$(function(){
    $("#next").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var form = $(this),
            page = form.attr("action"),
            page_nr = (/\d+$/.exec(page) || ["2"])[0];

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: page, 
            success: function(html){
                form.attr("action", page.substring(0, (page.length - page_nr.length)) + (+page_nr + 1));
                $("#results").append(html);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/WfrU7/

Comment: Thanks John, yes, it was a typo :)

Comment: (+1) It is a very clever way! I, myself,  try to avoid extra coding (processing stress) whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle these "need to keep history of" is, believe it or not, a dom element. We get so tied to programming, variables, and literals that we just forget the simple side of things. And, apparently, simple is what no one has in mind.

So, the "simple" solution is on the script of the page being loaded, save your querystring parameter (page=2 ... the 2) on a

```
<span id='curPageNumber' style='display:none; '>
```

in the loaded page. In the next call, all you have to to is, for example, onSubmit='functionSubmit(); ' and

```
function functionSubmit() {
    var action="load.php?page="+$('#curPageNumber').text()*1+1;
    $('#formID').attr('action',action);
    $('#formID').submit();
}
```